# I can't do the factorial calculation and addition function

Tags: python

The problem he faced is briefly. I need to write a function that calculates the factorial. This function must calculate the factorial of the numbers I send (of more than one number). After calculating the factorial of the numbers I sent him, he should add them all and send them back to me. I do both separately, but I cannot do it together. I leave the link of the codes.
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dRJnMT7fkt/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyCqv.jpg)

Comment: do you send values as an array or separately?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code - external links may not be reliable.  See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this:

```
def Faktoriyel(a):
    sonuc=0
    for f in a:       
        sonucumuz=1           
        for i in range(1,f+1):
            sonucumuz *= i    
        sonuc += sonucumuz  
    return sonuc
```

Here you go as you requested one function.
If it helps you please upvote and accept the answer.